# XBee Design and UART characteristics

Tags: serial, wireless, uart, xbee

I want to connect XBee to PC , does xbee send serial data or need UART to do that ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by XBee.  XBee is a communication protocol specification, like Ethernet. Your XBee implementation (module or chip) may have a UART or not.

Comment: I think most XBee modules use some sort of serial interface, but yes, OP needs to specify which specific device is intended for the application.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're probably looking for.
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8687

Provided you have another xbee somewhere communicating to the one plugged into your PC, download the drivers for that board, open up a serial terminal, set the baud rate to 9600 (xbee series 1 default) and away you go!